# Chart.js v3 - is annotation supported in version 3?

Tags: angular, charts

I have used 'annotation' inside options in version 2 chart, but after updating to version 3, it's not working neither I am able to find documentation regarding that. Below code was working in version 2.

```
options: {
 annotation: {
  annotations: [
   {
    drawTime: 'afterDraw',
    type: 'line',
    borderDash: [5],
    mode: 'horizontal',
    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
    borderColor: '#2E74E5',
    borderWidth: 2,
   }]
  },
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old version doesn't work with ChartJS 3.x.

Just use the last version of this Plugin, you can find it here:

[annotation for ChartJS 3.x](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/chartjs-plugin-annotation)

Actually many results of googling about ChartJS are referred on the version 2.x. it is a bit confusing, so pay attention on that.